# Microsoft Access Report ActiveX Control written using .Net Framework

Tags: .net, ms-access, activex, report

I apologize in advance for my bad english, i'm italian.
I have a problem. I'm Working on .Net ActiveX Control for Microsoft Access Report. The Control is build using COM Interface as contract and Interop Services like Attribute. The Control is retrieved by Access and work fine, now i need to work on "ControlSource", the Access's Property used for Data Source Column Selection in design mode.

The property "ControlSource" i tried to implement in Interface Contract is this:

```
    [DispId(0x1b)]
    string ControlSource { 
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
        [MethodImpl(
            MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, 
            MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x1b)] get; 
        [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
        [MethodImpl(
            MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, 
            MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x1b)] set; 
    }
```

But it still not work. Any Idea?
Thanks in advance for anyone who wants to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: using dot.net is not possible build MS Access Report Control!
VB6 or C is the solution!

I hope it is useful to someone in order to avoid unnecessary time spent searching for a solution that does not exist